How to retrieve PENDING purchases on the Android Play Store?
I need to query for pending purchases when my Android app launches so they can be processed by our server. I'm currently using BillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() to do this and it's working fine.
However, queryPurchaseHistoryAsync has been deprecated and Google recommends using BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync() instead. Unfortunately that call doesn't return purchases that are in the PENDING state, presumably because it's only using the local cache and PENDING state is only known by the Play Store server.
So my question is how do I retrieve all PENDING purchases now, without relying on a deprecated call?

According to google Document Google Doc
val billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
    .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
    .enablePendingPurchases() // Add this line
    .build()

Query Pending Purchases on App Launch
Using BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync()
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP) { billingResult, purchases ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                for (purchase in purchases) {
                    if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {
                        // Handle pending purchase
                        handlePendingPurchase(purchase)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Handle Pending Purchases in PurchasesUpdatedListener
Your PurchasesUpdatedListener will notify you whenever a purchase is updated, including state changes like PENDING to PURCHASED.
val purchasesUpdatedListener = PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                for (purchase in purchases) {
                    when (purchase.purchaseState) {
                        Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING -> {
                            // Handle pending purchase
                            handlePendingPurchase(purchase)
                        }
                        Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED -> {
                            // Handle completed purchase
                            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                                acknowledgePurchase(purchase)
                            }
                        }
                        Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE -> {
                            // Handle error or ignored state
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                // Handle user cancellation
            } else {
                // Handle other errors
            }
        }

Hope this help you

Thanks Rushi. I already had .enablePendingPurchases() in my builder, and also for anyone reading this, the version without parameters has been deprecated. The new one requires a PendingPurchasesParam

Also, this is basically my current implementation already and the problem is twofold. Firstly, PurchasesUpdatedListener is never called because I'm not starting a purchase flow. Second, the listener for queryPurchasesAsync() is called but 'purchases' is empty. There is in fact a pending purchase, but this method won't report it. I know there's a pending purchase because queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() reports it. But of course that's the method which has been deprecated.
